# Have a VPS and setup fillezilla to share files. How can I share files from a external hard drive that is connected to my main computer

Tags: filezilla, vps

Basically want to use the vps to run the FileZilla and share files that are on a external hd. I added it to the vps and can get connected via client side of FileZilla but get a error that I can't access the shared folder.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a vps with filezilla installed the files I want to share are on a external hard drive, when I get connect on the client side it will not give me access to the files shared from the external hard drive.